# Return / Print path of a selected file

Tags: c++, path, windows-10

I am trying to create a function that opens a dialog box, lets the user select a file, and then return the path of it as a std::string. I have this so far, but I am trying to get it so that it prints and returns the path as a string.

```
auto GetUserFile() {
    OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
    char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name 
    HWND hwnd{};              // owner window
    HANDLE hf;              // file handle

    // Initialize OPENFILENAME
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;
    // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
    // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0"; // I think this sets the file types that can be selected
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    // Display the Open dialog box. 

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE) {
        hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, GENERIC_READ, 0,(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            (HANDLE)NULL);

        std::cout << ofn.lpstrFile; // ?? prints a bunch of numbers and letters
        // return ofn.lpstrFile; // Want to change this to a string
    }
}
```

The windows documentation that I am using for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-common-dialog-boxes?redirectedfrom=MSDN#open_file) says that the lpstrFile member "contains the path and file name," but I am not sure how to actually get it into string form or even an understandable form for myself. I might just be using the wrong conversion methods, and I have tried converting `lpstrfile` to a c string and also a std::string, but they give random seeming numbers also or raise an access violation.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot right now but, unrelated details, this code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

OPENFILENAME ofn;
DWORD error_value;

using namespace std;

bool openFileDialog(TCHAR szFileName[])
{
    const TCHAR* FilterSpec = "All Files(.)\0*.*\0";
    const TCHAR* Title = "Open";

    const TCHAR* myDir = "C:\\c_plus_plus_trial";

    TCHAR szFileTitle[MAX_PATH] = { '\0' };

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

    *szFileName = 0;

    /* fill in non-variant fields of OPENFILENAME struct. */
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);

    ofn.hwndOwner = GetFocus();
    ofn.lpstrFilter = FilterSpec;
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = myDir; // Initial directory.
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = szFileTitle;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = Title;
    //ofn.lpstrDefExt = 0; // I've set to null for demonstration
    ofn.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;

    // false if failed or cancelled
    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == 1)
    {
        cout << "SUCCESS !!! \n";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failure :( \n";
        error_value = CommDlgExtendedError();
        cout << std::hex << error_value;

        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    TCHAR openedFileName[MAX_PATH];

    if (openFileDialog(openedFileName))
        std::cout << "File location\\name: " << openedFileName << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "User cancelled the operation\n";
}
```

It was taken from [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/272293/), and it requires that, for visual studio 2019, the character set is set to "not set"[image].